# How do I add a Ruby IF statement on the same line as plain text in HAML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I'm trying to add a simple IF statement on the same line as some text in HAML:

```
%h2 Information about 
    - project.participants.each do |participant|
      - if participant != current_user
        %h2=link_to participant.full_name, participant
```

But the webpage displays:

Information about

(person's name)

How can I get it to display "Information about (person's name)" all on one line?

Thanks!

EDIT: This is how I would do it in HTML:

```
Information about <% project.participants.each do |participant| %> <% if participant != current_user %> <%= link_to participant.full_name, participant %>.
```

It would all be on one line.

Comment: Do you mean to display `Information about (person's name)` for every participant?  Can you not move the `Information about` h2 inside `each`?

Comment: How can I move that inside the each statement?

Comment: Can you show expected output in html?

Comment: That `erb` produces exactly same output as your `haml` except for the `h2` tags.

Comment: This should be in a helper anyway.

Comment: Yes but for some reason the HAML is breaking this up into two separate lines. I need the output on one single. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like:

```
- project.participants.each do |participant|
  - if participant != current_user
    %h2 
      %span
        Information about
      =link_to participant.full_name, participant
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the first `h2` tag to include more than a simple one-liner, add a break after it:

So instead of:

```
%h2 Information about
# => <h2>Information about</h2>
```

use:

```
%h2
  Information about
  .
  .
  .

# => <h2>
#      Information about
#      .
#      .
#      .
#    </h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pick those html markup elements which are displayed inline.

A few examples are:

```
%h2
  %em Information about
  =link_to participant.full_name, participant
```

or

```
%h2
  %span Information about
  =link_to participant.full_name, participantenter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

```
- project.participants.each do |participant|
  - if participant != current_user
    %h2="Information about #{link_to participant.full_name , participant}"
```

Comment: I tried this but I get `Information about <a href="/users/3">test user</a>`